# Update safe path to specific Java version (32 or 64) on Windows

Tags: java, windows

I need to install both 32 and 64 bit versions of JREs because I have some apps that need to load 32 bit shared objects and some that need 64.  AFAIK there is no way to specify 32 or 64 bit java without using the full path which includes the jre version number, and that changes with every Oracle update -- hence my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle`?

Comment: Yes, the C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath has entries only for the 64 bit java* executables

Comment: The "full path" is something _you_ provide during installation. The only thing you need to do is to specify the same path each time.